# Fujifilm X-T5 EXIF orientation says horizontal but image displays as portrait, why?

Tags: camera, metadata, exif

I have a photo blog where I use a script to differentiate between landscape and portrait photos (because they're displayed in different part of the page). I used to shoot with a Fujifilm X-T2 and mostly the script worked by looking at the EXIF orientation.

[image: From the MetaImage app]

However, now I shoot with a Fujifilm X-T5 and both landscape and portrait photos (at least that's how they appear in the MacOS Photos app and Finder) have an EXIF Orientation of "Horizontal (normal)". I've verified that in both my script and an EXIF metadata editor whereas X-T2 images had either:

- Rotate 270W (Portrait)
- Horizontal (normal) (Landscape)

Is there some other way I can programmatically determine the correct orientation of the photo?

Comment: Are these jpegs or RAF files? What are the results when you use the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3)?  My RAF samples show that there are two `Orientation`, one in `IFD0` and one in `IFD1`.  The latter is often the only one  listed when you don't include the [`-G` (`-groupNames`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#G-NUM-:NUM...--groupNames) and the [`-a` (`-duplicates`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#a---a--duplicates---duplicates), but it applies only to the thumbnail image

Comment: Also, the existence of the `Rotate` tag is interesting because that is normally found in MP4 based RAW file types such as CR3.